# Lunatic Cultist won't spawn!

Tags: terraria

I destroyed all the cultists near the tablet but the lunatic cultist won't spawn. I have checked everywhere to see if there are any left (including down the hole). I have provided a screenshot of it to show what I mean...

[image: Cultist Tablet w/o Cultists]

I need help because I would like to be able to use this world for pillar destroying as I prepped it for use on the pillars. I even made an AFK Moon Lord area so I could focus on just the pillars.

Comment: It might be that the Cultist can only spawn on solid bricks? Wait one in-game day and try again after placing some blocks over the hole

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There used to be some [problems](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/does-altering-the-dungeon-entrance-affect-cultists.24291/) in regards to the Lunatic Cultist spawning. I suppose they haven't been quite fixed. In general, to prevent any issues you should avoid altering the dungeon entrance. Specifically removing dungeon bricks. It messes with the boss and the cultists spawn point.

Rebuilding the entrance may solve the issue, however since you already killed the cultist you may have to wait 2 or 3 in-game days. If they still don't spawn, try 5-6 days. If there's still no luck I really wouldn't keep trying on that world.

Answer (score -5):

I also had the same problem, try restarting the system.