# Cultists aren't spawning and nothing worked

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I tried reloading, killing Golem again,removing walls from the outer dungeon entrance, finishing all the events I had at the time, everything, and nothing worked. And I'm playing on console so they should spawn.

Comment: There is a related post [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257823/lunatic-cultist-wont-spawn). It sounds liked you **don't** want to modify the dungeon entrance, which it appears you have.  I'm pretty sure I've destroyed some of the dungeon entrance before though and it works fine for me

Comment: Could you confirm that you're on the latest console version (1.4.4) and maybe share a screenshot of the dungeon entrance? You seem to have already tried the common fixes related to [Cultist spawn criteria](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Cultists#Notes)