# Why is it when I broke a few bricks from the floor of a dungeon, it doesn't spawn cultists or the tablet?

Tags: terraria

When exploring my new master world and coming across the dungeon. I accidentally broke a few bricks from the entrance of the dungeon floor. I placed them back and didn't think much of it. After defeating golem and waiting for a few days, I noticed the cultists nor the tablet still didn't spawn.

After investigating for a bit, I realised the bricks I broke caused it, and even placing them back doesn't help. If you know why this happens and how to fix it, I will be more than happy for you to tell me.

Comment: Since you mentioned your world is new, are you on hard mode? They're hard mode exclusive enemies and item.

Comment: Yes, my world is on hardmode, and golem was defeated (a long time ago). Yet still they won't spawn

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what the area around the dungeon entrance looks like? I'd like to check it against their spawn criteria on the wiki. Include the height, position, world size, and all that technical junk if you're able.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lunatic Cultist won't spawn!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257823/lunatic-cultist-wont-spawn)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to fix this, because for the Endgame Cultists to spawn, there needs to be *naturally placed* **Cursed Dungeon Bricks** at the entrance to the Dungeon where the Cultists need to spawn.

Answer (score -2):

Sadly, there is actually no way to fix this.

Comment: Please try to be more specific when answering questions.